# What cache-hit-rate is needed to maintain the average Lookup Time in this CAM

Tags: data-structures, average, lookup

I hate a question from Uni which has me completely stumped.

A system often makes a certain kind of Lookup; first in a CAM-memory which always takes **m** time. The probability of getting a hit is **P** and if there is no hit it'll make a lookup in a table in the main memory. The lookup is done by indexing in a vector. The lookup in the main memory always results in a hit, and accessing the main memory takes **M** time.

However, the values used as keys in the indexing are spread out and thus the vector ends up unnecessarily large. To fix this issue the vector will be replaced by another data structure that requires two indexings for a lookup.

**The Question:** What new hit-probability **P_new** is needed for the average lookup-time to remain the same as with the old data structure? There are 5 options given, though more than one may be correct.

1. P_new = P + 0.5
2. P_new = ((P+1)*M + Pm)*(M+m)
3. P_new = (1 - 2P) / 2
4. P_new = (P+1)*M / 2
5. P_new = (P+1) / 2

If anyone have any idea which of these are correct (and more importantly; why it's correct and the others incorrect) I would be extremely grateful if you could enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Soo, ended up solving it by using the answer from a previous question which defined the average lookup time formula as *T = (1-P)M + m*

Since the time T should be the same in both cases, and the only difference is that a lookup in the main memory now takes twice as long, we get *(1-P)M + m = (1-P_new)2M + m* which can then be simplified.

(1-P)M = (1-P_new)2M

1 - P = 2 * (1-P_new) = 2 - 2*P_new

P - 1 = 2*P_new - 2

P + 1 = 2 * P_new

(P + 1) / 2 = P_new

**Thus;** the correct answer is Nr_5